# Javascript: assigning the second optional argument without assigning the first

Tags: javascript, optional-arguments

I'm trying to create a function that has multiple optional arguments. I am then trying to only assign the second argument without having to also assign the first one.

```
function foo(bar, zar) {
  bar = bar || 5;
  zar = zar || 2;

  return bar * zar;
}

foo()      //10
foo(7)     //14
foo(7, 3)  //21
foo(zar=5) //10 <-- why is this not 25?
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How will the function know it's the second parameter if there is no first parameter? If the first and the second are different types you may be able to use *typeof*.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the easiest way to handle this kind of situation is to instead use an object for the parameter, with default field values via the ES6 syntax.

```js
function foo({ bar = 5, zar = 2 } = {}) {
  console.log(bar * zar);
}

foo() //10
foo({ bar: 7 }) //14
foo({ bar: 7, zar: 3 }) //21
foo({ zar: 5 }) //25
```

For reference, see: [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) and [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `undefined` for whatever parameters you would want to use as defaults.

`foo(undefined, 5);`

Also, if you are free to use ES6, you can simplify your function a little and declare your optional parameters like so:

`function foo(bar = 5, zar = 2) { }`

Answer (score 0):

Use `void 0` instead of the arguments you don't want to supply.

For example:
`foo(void 0,zar=5);`

Any unfilled argument will be `undefined`.

You cannot pass the second parameter without passing the first, but you can pass `undefined`.
In the function, you can check for `undefine`d and replace with a default value.

Alternately, you can use an object argument to imitate keyword arguments.

Comment: What? No. I want to have to option of supplying it in some cases or not supply it if I don't need it.

Comment: `void 0` is just a shorthand way to write `undefined`. `zar=5` is probably not what they want though. Just `foo(undefined, 5)`

Comment: @4castle Yes its shorter but `undefined` can be changed, where as `void` is an operator, which cannot be overridden in javascript and always returns the value `undefined`.

Comment: I didn't know about `void 0`. But that might work in this case, but that is still assigning the first argument. In my actual case, I have about 15 arguments and the one I need to sometimes assign is at the end.